# Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 76

Tags: java, android, uri, http-get

I am getting an error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 76.
Tried all the 3 examples.Unable to fix it .Tried url_encode but its not taking the components:locality part into consideration.How do I make this url work .Thanks in Advance.

```
BufferedReader in = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            URI website = new URI("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:Spokane|country=us|administrative_area:washington&address="+newText+"&sensor=false");
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = in.readLine();

            data = line;
            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And

```
                            String uri =("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:Spokane|country=us|administrative_area:washington&address="+newText+"&sensor=false");

                            uri=URLEncoder.encode(uri,"UTF-8");

                            HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(uri);
                            ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                            data = hClient.execute(hGet,rHandler);
                            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And

```
String urlstr="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
                String str_parameters = "components=locality:Spokane|country=us|administrative_area:washington";
                String encodedparams = URLEncoder.encode(str_parameters,"UTF-8")+"&address="+URLEncoder.encode(newText, "UTF-8")+"&sensor="+URLEncoder.encode("false", "UTF-8");

                String str_finalurl=urlstr+encodedparams;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character at 76 is `|`, which might be the cause of the issue.  Have you tried replacing it with the hexadecimal format `%7C`, forming this: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:Spokane%7Ccountry=us%7Cadministrative_area:washington&address="+newText+"&sensor=false`?

Also, is `newText` defined?